# Dataset extraction for skeletal joints in openni2

Tags: c++, openni, kinect-v2

I want to extract the skeletal data in form of x,y,z co-ordinates from openni2, is there any way to do this using C++ language? I am still a beginner and there's not much documentation available when I checked. I added openni2 files in visual studio and can open the Kinect camera but need the function to extract the data in CSV format, if there is blog or tutorial for this problem, please let me know. Thanks in advance.